# how to convert the bytes to int64 in the python

Tags: python

My question is:

- how can we convert the bytes to int64 in python

in C# we could use `BitConverter.ToInt64()`for transfer the bytes to int64.
but I didn't find similar function in the python.
how can I do it in the python. I just find the `int.from_bytes()`.

input: System.Byte[], \x12\x77\x2b\xca\x9b\x62\xa2\x72\x9e\xc8\xb7\xa7\x82\xd8\x4c\xba\xcb\x41\x78\x4c\x5a\x72\xdd\xf6

output: 4666902099556679087

Comment: What result do you need exactly? "int64" is not a Python type, perhaps, are you working with numpy?

Comment: Could you please provide sample input and expected output ?

Comment: Unlike C# where you have different `int` types like `short`, `int`, `long` (64bit int)  - there's just one `int` type that would store a 64bit value on a 64bit machine or 32bit value on a 32bit machine. Just use the function you've already found.

Comment: That's a lot of bytes you've got there, more than what would fit in a 64-bit integer. What's the relationship between that byte sequence and 4666902099556679087 supposed to be?

Comment: if i use bitcoverter.toint64(input), then i get the output 4666902099556679087

Answer (score 0):

In python, there is only `int` and no `int32` and `int64`. You can easily convert bytes string to `int` (supposing you are using only builtin types and not e.g. numpy):

```py
bytesstr = bytes("123") # the bytes string
numstr = bytesstr.decode() # convert bytes string to normal string
num = int(numstr) # convert normal string to number
```